# What is a modern way of doing hyperparameter optimization?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, hyperparameters

I'm not asking search methods such as grid search, random search etc....

I'm using Pytorch, and I have to test many different hyperparameters(learning rate, epoch, models etc) and see what produces best result. I know I have to save checkpoints(.pth file) and its corresponding metadata. How do I do this the modern way?

The only way I can think of right now is to save the results in a csv file, and include the metadata(name of .pth file, hyperparameter etc) in the same csv file. Is there any other way I can do this more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there are modern logging and reporting tools for these tasks, check MLFlow - for instance - it will allow saving information on the data used for training and evaluating, the hyperparameters and any wanted extra labeling information.